# Stack exchange occasionally freezes while writing an answer or editing

Tags: bug, status-norepro

**Specifications:** I am using Math Stack Exchange in Google Chrome, on my laptop which is connected to the internet by an ethernet cable.  I am located just outside of Paris, France.  **Edit:**  Google Chrome Version 17.

**Problem:**  For some reason, while typing out an answer on Math Stack Exchange, or editing an answer, the site will freeze.  (Similarly for the meta.math page)  Google chrome itself does not freeze, I can open other tabs and visit other sites.   I can open a tab and visit the same page, closing the frozen page, but the problem is I lose the answer I was typing out.  Sometimes a partly saved version will still be there, but the most recent part will be lost.  (Or all of the edit will be lost)  This is extremely frustrating, and on more then one occasion I have just altogether abandoned the attempt to provide an answer.

**Cause:** Unfortunately, I don't even know how to recreate the error.  It seems to happen almost randomly, sometimes I can go through an edit or writing an answer without anything happening.  I am not sure if this is Google Chromes fault, as this doesn't happen for any other webpage I use, and Chrome seems to be running normally.

Any help would be appreciated, this has been happening for about 3 weeks, and I find myself answering less questions from inconvenience.

> **Edit** According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), as of February 13, 2012, Google Chrome version 17 is unsupported by Stack Exchange.  However, according [to this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history), Google Chrome was updated, and version 17 became the stable current version on February 8th 2012.  This is roughly the time these problems started occurring.  It seems plausible that this could be causing the problem.

Comment: what version Chrome? As of now, supported versions are 15, 16 and possibly 14 - per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @gnat: I am using version 17.  I have updated the post.

Comment: @gnat:  This seems to explain things.  As of the 8th of February 2012, Google changed 17 to the current stable version.  This is around the time I started having these problems.

Comment: Do you have any chrome extensions installed? If so, what are they?

Comment: There are [other users seeing this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/mse-becomes-unresponsive-while-i-am-answering-questions), as well - we're reaching out to the MathJax developers for help.

Comment: @Jarrod The freezes happen for me for *every* nontrivial answer I compose on MSE in Chrome (17.0.963.56). For heavy users like I, it makes the site unusable with Chrome. IMO this is by far the worst bug in the couple years of MSE's life.

Comment: Same here (Chrome 18.0.1025.118 beta-m, Win-7-64)

Comment: @Jarrod The bug still exists and it's still a showstopper for me, making Chrome unsable with MathJax, see my [bug report here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4037/242) Could you please notify the appropriate folks.

Comment: @BillDubuque can you point me to specific answers that you were composing that caused the crashes, please?

Comment: From users on Math, it appears that this was isolated to Chrome 18.0 and the current versions of the browser do not exhibit the issue.

Comment: For completeness,  the issue spanned the versions 17--23 of Chrome (approximately).